# using PHP include to get local js kosher?

Tags: javascript, php, include, local

I have searched the following and it seems no one evan asks about, so I assume there is something facepalm dumb about it:
In a php file

```
... php code
    ?><script type="text/javascript> <?php include js/filename.js ?></script>
<?php
... php code
```

Comment: There would be no point in doing that. If you want to create JavaScript with PHP, just use a `.php` file extension in your HTML script tag src, then write the JavaScript creating PHP on the `.php` page.

Comment: Actually, as Brad mentioned below, I was trying to avoid another round trip to get a small number of JS glue functions used by this page alone.
As per suggestions seen other places, I could have pasted the JS directly into the page.
My assumption, which seemed true in my host's situation, the delay of reading the file on the host was much smaller than the transit wait time.
Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you're trying to do is bundle your JS into your HTML output.  There are in fact several use cases for this, but they don't come up often.  For example, I had a web application that would load on game consoles which had no cache.  As a micro-optimization, I'd just bundle all the scripts and CSS into the HTML to reduce the number of HTTP requests.

Generally speaking though, there are downsides to this.  Suppose you want to use that same JavaScript on multiple pages.  Where the script could have been loaded on Page A, cached, and then immediately available for Page B, now you have to load the whole thing again for Page B.  Also, don't forget that proxy servers cache static resources well.  If you're creating pages dynamically, those probably aren't going to be cached, even though the JavaScript could be.

Now, onto the bundling technique... what you're doing is facepalm indeed.  By using `include()`, you're telling PHP to execute the contents of that file as if it were PHP.  That's not a PHP file (I assume anyway), that's JavaScript.  It's unlikely, but if `<?php` were to end up in that file, you're going to end up executing code you didn't intend to execute server-side.  What's worse is that you're wasting CPU by having PHP look for its tokens.  [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is what you'd want instead, which would pass through the contents of that file.

Other things to be aware of are escaping and such.  You're now using a plain JS file in the context of HTML.  Caution is needed.

Best to use an existing bundler tool for this.  I don't have any specific recommendations at the moment... I haven't found one in PHP I particularly like.

Comment: Missed the edit window:
Thanks for the input, especially the readfile.
Indeed, I was having some delay in getting my included (homegrown) js file to the browser the first time (and bloci=king other stuff). I have since moved most of the other includes to CDN.
There's also the downside of exposing my internal routines in the "view source"
Good point about the (probably unlikely, especially for a file I write) chance that the js file has a <?php in it.